# Accdess data from onPreviewFrame inside a java class to another activity: Android

Tags: android, image-processing, camera

I am doing some image processing with my android camera. It is taking the raw data in NV21 format and then converting it into RGB format to get the average R value of each frame. The frame rate is set to 16 with optimal resolution of the phone. There were a lot of conversion algorithms and the one I'm using works quite well. However, the problem that I'm stuck with is that i want to plot a graph of the R value against time and since I am calling the conversion inside onPreviewFrame, I cannot figure out how to get the value of the R from this method to the main activity where i can perform the graph processing.

my onPreviewMethod of camera class is:

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera){

    //check if data is null
    if (data == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();

    Camera.Size size = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();

    //check if size is null
    if(size == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();


    //set resolution of camera view to optimal setting
    int width = size.width;
    int height = size.height;
    Log.d("Resolution ", " "+String.valueOf(width)+" "+String.valueOf(height));


    //call ImageProcess on the data to decode YUV420SP to RGB
    imgAvg = ImageProcessing.decodeYUV420SPtoRedAvg(data, width, height);
    imageIntensity = imgAvg/255;

    //set value of Y on the text view
    TextView valueOfY = (TextView)getRootView().findViewById(R.id.valueY);
    valueY = imgAvg;
    valueOfY.setText(Double.toString(imgAvg));

}
```

in here the **imgAvg** variable stores the average R value of each frame. The log shows correct results and there are 16 results per second. I want to access this data from the main activity where i am plotting the graph. What is the correct way to do it? Can i somehow directly access this data, or do i need to store the data in some form then access it from another activity. (N.B I would like  to avoid saving the entire video and do the image processing.) Thank you.

Comment: You can use the interface. It very easy!

Comment: thank for the reply. can you please elaborate your suggestion a bit?

Comment: Ok. see my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
public class Camera {

public interface PreviewReadyCallback {
  void onPreviewFrame(String value1, int value2, Double value3, Float value4, Bitmap value5); // Any value you want to get
}




PreviewReadyCallback mPreviewReadyCallback = null;

public void setOnPreviewReady(PreviewReadyCallback cb) {
    mPreviewReadyCallback = cb;
}

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera){

//check if data is null
if (data == null)
    throw new NullPointerException();

Camera.Size size = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();

//check if size is null
if(size == null)
    throw new NullPointerException();


//set resolution of camera view to optimal setting
int width = size.width;
int height = size.height;
Log.d("Resolution ", " "+String.valueOf(width)+" "+String.valueOf(height));


//call ImageProcess on the data to decode YUV420SP to RGB
imgAvg = ImageProcessing.decodeYUV420SPtoRedAvg(data, width, height);
imageIntensity = imgAvg/255;

//set value of Y on the text view
TextView valueOfY = (TextView)getRootView().findViewById(R.id.valueY);
valueY = imgAvg;
valueOfY.setText(Double.toString(imgAvg));
mPreviewReadyCallback.onPreviewFrame(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5);

} 
}
```

in YourActivity

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements PreviewReadyCallback{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Camera camera = new Camera();
     camera.setOnPreviewReady(this);
}
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(String value1, int value2, Double value3, Float value4, Bitmap value5) {

  // Code here!

   }
 }
```